# Add error styling to inputs in Redux-Form

Tags: javascript, redux-form

I'm learning Redux-Form and with Bulma css styling.  I would like to add the class "is-danger" to the input when there is a touched error.  I'm working from the example in the docs, I'm trying something like this:

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
    <div className="field">
    <label className="label">{label}</label>
    <input className="input {touched && error&& is-danger)" {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
{touched && ((error && <p className="help is-danger">{error}</p>) || (warning && <p className="help is-danger">{warning}</p>))}

</div>
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like classnames:

```
<input 
    className={classnames(input, { is-danger: touched && error })} 
    {...input} 
    placeholder={label} 
    type={type} />
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames